# How to create Unity 2D enemy AI varying directional Animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically what i am trying to do is create an animation script that does not just take simple direction like Up(0,1),Down(0,-1),Left(-1,0),Right(1,0)(Those numbers being vectors) but to have range of directions for to fill in the gap between those directions and play the more dominant direction Up,Down,Left,Right.
So each quarter section below to be set to an animation.

[image]

I have created a few scripts to try and achieve this i came up with one that wasn't perfect but it did work when dragging the enemies around in the scene editor while the game was running. When using their movements scripts for their movement it did not work. The animation script is below and underneath that how i move the enemies.

Below would be how i calculate the direction the enemy was moving:

```
IEnumerator directionFinder()
{
   // while (true)
    //{
        Vector3 previousPosition = transform.position;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/10);
        currentPosition = transform.position;
        currentPosition.x = currentPosition.x - previousPosition.x;
        currentPosition.y = currentPosition.y - previousPosition.y;
        currentPosition.z = 0f;

        angle = (Mathf.Atan2(currentPosition.y, currentPosition.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

        if(angle < 0)
        {
            angle = Mathf.Abs(angle) + 180;
        }

   // } 
}
```

Then this is what calculated which animation to use:

```
 void animationDirection()
{

    if (angle == 0)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Move", currentAnim);
    }
    if (angle > 45 && angle <135)//W
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Move", 1);
        currentAnim = 1;
    }
    else if (angle > 135 && angle < 225)//A
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Move", 2);
        currentAnim = 2;
    }
    else if (angle > 225 && angle < 315)//S
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Move", 3);
        currentAnim = 3;
    }
    else if((angle < 45 && angle >= 0) || (angle > 315 && angle <= 0))//D
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Move", 4);
        currentAnim = 4;
    }
}
```

This using the code below it would move to the waypoint that was selected via the rest of my code that would just loop through a set of waypoints changing the waypoint when it arrived at one.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[waypointNUmber].transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Below I tried another way but it did not work and created weird buggy animations:

```
 IEnumerator directionalAnimation()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Debug.Log("working");
        Vector2 previousPosition = transform.position;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/10);
        Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;
        Vector2 direction = (previousPosition - currentPosition).normalized;

        float moveX = direction.x;
        float moveY = direction.y;

        if (moveX < 0)
        {
            moveXNegative = true;
            moveX = Mathf.Abs(moveX);
        }
        if (moveY < 0)
        {
            moveYNegative = true;
            moveY = Mathf.Abs(moveY);
        }

        if (direction.magnitude != 0)
        {
            if (moveX > moveY)
            {
                if (moveXNegative)
                {
                    //left
                    Walking = true;
                    anim.SetInteger("Move", 2);
                    moveYNegative = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Right
                    Walking = true;
                    anim.SetInteger("Move", 4);
                    moveYNegative = false;
                }
            }
            else if (moveY > moveX)
            {
                if (moveYNegative)
                {
                    //Down
                    Walking = true;
                    anim.SetInteger("Move", 3);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Up
                    Walking = true;
                    anim.SetInteger("Move", 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            source.Pause();
            Walking = false;
        }

        if (Walking)
        {
            source.UnPause();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I think `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/10);` could be causing the weird behaviour, but i'm not sure. 1/10 will always be 0, since you're dividing two integers. So maybe `previousPosition` and `currentPosition` are always getting the same value. Try to change it to 1f/10. Just a guess

Comment: Replaced 1/10 it with 0.1f as i am trying to do it 10 times a second, other wise the vector difference is too small for unity, if it runs every frame. Sadly didn't change anything.